# Notification of Flag on Questions that need moderation

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderation

One suggestion that I have is with the flagging system. While you can tell what questions you have flagged under your profile, it would be handy to have a display element on the question that you flag. This display element could be like the one that is used to show a user had up or down voted an answer. This way if you go back at a later time, you can tell that you have previously flagged that question for moderation.